# Formatting cell values from OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm opening up xlsx files as a package and reading the contents of the xml files. I'm able to get the shared strings, borders, etc that I need and it's orders of magnitude faster than when I was using Interop. The only issue I have is when it comes to pulling out numbers and formatting them properly based on what the formatting is in the Excel file.

Is there a generic function somewhere that takes a value and a format and returns the formatted string? For example, if I have the value 31502008 and the custom format "$* #,##0_);$* (#,##0)" is there a simple way to get what Excel shows (which is $31,502,008). Obviously Excel knows how to handle it, but I have some sheets that have a crazy number of custom formats and I'm wondering how best to ensure that the string I get back in code matches what is seen in Excel.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for any help.